# NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO Happening with Ajax and Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am really stuck with this.

I get the error NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO when I have an Ajax call to my view in Django. The view takes the post data and returns the HTML as a string.

Under the success part of the Ajax call, I get this error when trying to alert the data. The JS code looks as below:

```
  function viewConnections(routeids) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/planner/viewconnections/",
    data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
            routeids : routeids.toString() },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```